# CloudFlare JS challenge is breaking my SPA

Tags: reactjs, laravel, security, cors, cloudflare

I have a React based SPA that is hosted via S3 on one subdomain, react.mydomain.com ... It communicates with a PHP REST API that is hosted on a VPS on another subdomain, api.mydomain.com . The api.mydomain.com is behind CloudFlare. The webapp is behind CloudFront since it is on AWS.

I am having issues w/ bot requests directly to the API flooding my VPS, and I would like to use the JS challenge functionality with CloudFlare to mitigate.

However, what seems to be happening is that users are able to load the React webapp (which is not behind CloudFlare). Then, the request that will prompt the JS challenge will fail with a 503 response instantly, because it is an AJAX request and it is incompatible with the Javascript challenge.

I thought I may be able to handle this by catching the error and redirecting. However, if I manually force my own browser to navigate to the api.mydomain.com URL, I will see the CloudFlare challenge and pass it. However, if I then navigate back to my react.mydomain.com SPA, the OPTIONS requests will fail because it cannot attach the cookie that tells CloudFlare it has passed.

I don't understand how to adjust my infrastructure so that I can take advantage of using the JS challenge. At the moment I am restricted to using rate limiting, but I have found that I am still letting in what seems like ~75% or more of the unwanted bot traffic through by the time I get severe enough that users start complaining.

Comment: I don't know about cloudflare, but I've seen other solutions configure the bot protection tracking cookie to include the scope of both frontend and API domains. And to take care of the main problem, you need to have your JS code detect the challenge, execute it (e.g. with `eval()`), wait for the challenge to finish, and rerun the request.

Answer (score -1):

If you have backend access, you may be able to use NPM and `process.kill(process.pid)` upon detection of a bot as a temporary solution.

Comment: It (coincidentally) creates a [website] closed the connection error which is extremely hard for a _human_ to bypass, and therefore would block headless bots efficiently.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest not to host spa in s3 only file uploads or attachments to s3

Host on Ec2 and block all access through security Group Policy
only allow Cloudflare IP's
which are listed here https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

You can also use Amazon AWS Lambda serverless for hosting instead of s3
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/?c=ser&sec=srv

Comment: S3, especially with CloudFront in front of it, is a perfectly suitable and scalable solution to host a single page application. Hosting on EC2 or using a Lambda is not enough. A single page application on EC2 will still have to be served with either a Node.js service or an Apache server, for example. A Lambda will have to be integrated to API Gateway in order to serve the content. Both of these solutions seem clunky for a SPA whereas S3 offers a straightforward solution. It looks like the problem that the user is encountering is not related to the AWS service used for the app.